# Is there some way (in Linux) to set how syslog writes its timestamp

Tags: linux, centos, syslog

My syslog configuration (the default CentOS 5.3 configuration) writes out time stamps that look like

```
Jan  1 00:00:00 message
```

I would like the timestamp to contain the year.  Preferably it would look like

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 message
```

Is there any way to configure syslog to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 5.4 uses sysklogd by default, syslog-ng is not provided*.There is no mention of how to alter the date format in the syslog.conf manpage.  rsyslog is available through the default repositories and, glancing at [its manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyslog.conf), it may do what you want.

*See [Where can I find syslog-ng in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5?](http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-17608)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this is the path I will have to go down.  We don't have enough time to drop in rsyslog now, but I think it will work well for version 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

What version of syslog does CentOS use?

Syslog-NG will let you change the template to use $FULLDATE or $ISODATE which seems to do what you want.

[Syslog-ng Mailing List documenting templates](https://lists.balabit.hu/pipermail/syslog-ng/2001-January/001153.html)

Comment: An ISO date is pretty much what I am looking for. The version reported by `syslogd -v` is `syslogd 1.4.1`.

Comment: +1 for using syslog-ng over syslogd, much more powerful and flexible.